# PHP nl2br posting duplicate <br/>'s?

Tags: php

I'm using the following code to post the content of a text box to an HTML file. When the info is submitted, I want there to be `<br/>` inserted where line-breaks are. I thought using this code would fix the problem:

`$content = nl2br($_POST['content']);`

But it seems to produce the following if there is already a `<br />` in place:

> Lorum ipsum.`<br /><br />`

How do I remedy this?

The post code:

```
<?php
$fn = "people.html";
if (isset($_POST['content']))
{
    $content = stripslashes('content');
    $content = nl2br($_POST['content']);
    $fp = fopen($fn,"w") or die ("Error opening file in write mode!");
    fputs($fp,$content);
    fclose($fp) or die ("Error closing file!");
}
?>
```

How it's being submitted:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>" method="post">
    <textarea rows="25" cols="40" name="content"><?php readfile($fn); ?></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Sauver"> 
</form>
```

Comment: What does the $_POST data look like?

Comment: From what you are saying, the content is `Lorem ipsum. <br />\n`? Then this is a perfectly expected result.

Comment: It looks like what I put in the quotes in my post, `Lorum ipsum.<br /><br />`

Comment: @deceze No, what I'm trying to accomplish is that when I type something in my text box which has a line break, it records this line break as `<br />` and submits it to the `.html` file. What's happening is if that is continues putting line-breaks in even after one is already there. Say I have one line-break, and I hit submit, it produces one `<br />`. If I submit it again, there are two, etc.

Comment: How are you submitting it again?

Comment: @Charlie: wrong. It puts line breaks **only** when there is a new line character, without any expectations and other magic

Comment: I updated it with how I'm submitting it. @zerkms, Is there a way to accomplish what I'm looking for then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//$content = stripslashes('content');
$content = preg_replace('~\s*<br ?/?>\s*~',"<br />",$_POST['content']);
$content = nl2br($content);
```

Something like that should strip excess whitespace around line breaks for you.

Also, why are you using stripslashes? That should only be necessary if you have magic quotes on, and you  shouldn't have magic quotes on. You also have got that line's syntax wrong anyway.

edit: Still trying to interpret what you're saying. I'm thinking this might help:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>" method="post">
    <textarea rows="25" cols="40" name="content"><?htmlentities(preg_replace('~\s*<br ?/?>\s*~i',"\n",(file_get_content($fn))); ?></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Sauver"> 
</form>'
```

Will start with the correct data. Perhaps.

Comment: I'm getting the same problem as before. If I submit the following text, `First line. **LINEBREAK** Second line.`, it posts the following code: `First line.<br />Second line.`. After the page submits the code, it reloads and shows the changes though this line in the `<textarea>`, `<?php readfile($fn); ?>`. If I submit the form again, without making any changes, it ads a second `<br/>` to the previous ones: `First line.<br /><br />Second line.`

Comment: It is never a good idea to repair the data broken by some issue, instead of fixing the roots of the issue

Comment: You should be filling your textbox with `<?=htmlentities(file_get_contents($fn))?>` for starters. I'm with @zerkms on this - there's a root issue, and while my code will patch it, it's not a proper fix. Can you post an example of the content of `$fn`?

Comment: Actually I think you might even want to go all out with `<?=htmlentities(preg_replace('~\s*<br ?/?>\s*~',"\n",file_get_contents($fn)))?>` when reading the file into the text box - just trying to figure out exactly what you're asking, but that might help...

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, if the html your inserting already contains a `<br />` tag then it adds two because of the `\n` after the `<br />`, to remedy this you would need to strip the  **extra** break tag from the input using str_replace or regex.

Then when echoing result back to the textarea you should use: `<?=htmlentities(file_get_contents($fn))?>` as SpoonNZ suggested.

**note:** using user submitted html without passing through `htmlentities` or `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` within a form will open you upto XSS

Answer (score 2):

You should not be storing your line breaks as `<br>` in your persistent storage (your text file). In your text file, line breaks should be stored as line breaks (`"\n"`). You should only transform them into HTML `<br>` tags when you output them into HTML. You also need to escape any user supplied content you put into HTML (for why, read [The Great Escapism](http://kunststube.net/escapism)).

```
if (!empty($_POST['content'])) {
    file_put_contents('people.txt', $_POST['content']);
}
```

Then:

```
<textarea rows="25" cols="40" name="content"><?php
    echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents('people.txt')));
?></textarea>
```

This way line breaks are line breaks *at all times*, they just need to be converted to `<br>`s because that's the only way to conserve them in an HTML context.

As for why line breaks are doubling, there simply seems to be an additional line break added at some point, possibly by the browser when the textarea content is submitted. You may want to `trim` your input/output to avoid any leading or trailing whitespace.